# Python lineage naming with clustered dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, hierarchical-clustering, data-lineage

I have a dataframe

```
sample1  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 L1
sample2  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 L1-1
sample3  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 L1-1-1
sample4  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 L1-1-1-1
sample5  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 L1-1-2
sample6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 L1-1-2-1
sample7  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 L1-1-3
sample8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 L1-2
sample9  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 L1-2-1
sample10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 L1-2-2
sample11 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 L2
sample12 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 L2-1
sample13 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 L2-1-1
sample14 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 L2-1-1-1
sample15 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 L2-2
sample16 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 L2-3
```

As you can see, each row is clustered.

I want to name "lineage-based" labeling to each sample.

For example, sample1 will be lin1 because it is first to appear, sample2 will be lin1-1.

Sample3 will be lin1-1-1, sample4 will be lin1-1-1-1.

Next, sample5 will be lin1-2, sample6 will be lin1-2-1...

Sample11 will be a new start for the lineage, lin2.

My original idea for the naming was.

"sample1 is lin1, if next sample is included in the previous sample, lin1 + "-1"
if not, lin(1+1)"

sample1 -> lin1

sample2 -> lin1-1 (sample2 is included in sample1)

sample3 -> lin1-1-1 (sample3 is included in sample2)

sample4 -> lin1-1-1-1 (sample4 is included in sample3)

sample5 -> lin1-1-2 (sample5 is not included in sample4)
.... logic like this.

I couldn't make this logic into a python script.

Comment: Can you please show your final expected result (from sample1 to sample16)?

Comment: @jasonwong I have added that information in the dataframe thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in several steps.

Step 1. Data preprocessing

Sort the data in descending order and remove duplicate, otherwise it may not work. Assume done.

```py
import numpy as np

data = '''sample1  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
sample2  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
sample3  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
sample4  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sample5  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
sample6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
sample7  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
sample8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
sample9  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
sample10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
sample11 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sample12 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sample13 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sample14 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sample15 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sample16 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'''

data = [x.split() for x in data.split('\n')]
data = [x[1:] for x in data]
data = np.array(data, dtype=int)  
data
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Step 2. Encode the sample to position. Each element is a frozenset.

```py
nrow, ncol = data.shape

def to_position(sample):
    ncol = len(sample)
    return frozenset(i for i in range(ncol) if sample[i] == 1)

position = [to_position(data[i]) for i in range(nrow)]
# print(position)
```

Step 3. Assign each sample position to a cluster, where the cluster is represented as a tuple for now.

```py
def assign_cluster(sample, clusters, parent):
    if parent not in clusters:
        clusters[parent] = sample
    elif sample < clusters[parent]:
        # Find child
        parent = parent + (0,)
        assign_cluster(sample, clusters, parent)
    else:
        # Find siblings
        parent = parent[:-1] + (parent[-1] + 1, )
        assign_cluster(sample, clusters, parent)


clusters = {}
root = (0,)
clusters[root] = position[0]
for i in range(1, nrow):
    sample = position[i]
    assign_cluster(sample, clusters, parent=root)

# print(clusters)
```

Step 4. Convert cluster to string and show result.

```py
def cluster_to_string(c):
    c = [str(_ + 1) for _ in c]
    return 'L' + '-'.join(c)

position_dict = {v: k for k, v in clusters.items()}

for sample in data:
    sample = to_position(sample)
    c = position_dict[sample]
    print(cluster_to_string(c))
```

```
L1
L1-1
L1-1-1
L1-1-1-1
L1-1-2
L1-1-2-1
L1-1-3
L1-2
L1-2-1
L1-2-2
L2
L2-1
L2-1-1
L2-1-1-1
L2-2
L2-3
```

Comment: Wow.. amazing solution.. thank you